# LitElement and until directive - How to get called back when result from until is rendered?

Tags: javascript, lit

I am using LitElement and the until directive. Assume I am loading some data from the server. When this data is available, i want to render the data. And assume i am rendering some element where, for whatever reason, i need to get the DOM reference to manipulate it or call a method. Normally, this can be done with the firstUpdated or updated callbacks on the element. But with the until directive in between, I am not sure how to get called back after the until had rendered.
See my code below:

```
import { LitElement, css, html } from "lit";
import { until } from "lit/directives/until.js";

export class MyComponent extends LitElement {
  static properties = {};

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      ${until(
        this.fetchData(),
        html`
          loading....
        `
      )}
    `;
  }

  async fetchData() {
    return html`
      <div id="elem">Element loaded</div>
    `;
  }

  updated() {
    console.log("Trying to access div: " + document.querySelector("#elem"));
  }
}

customElements.define("my-component", MyComponent);
```

https://codepen.io/38leinaD/pen/GRzQVoE

This always prints `Trying to access div: null`. Without the until, it would work.
What is the right way to get called back after the elements in the until are rendered?

Thanks,
Daniel

UPDATE:
When i copied the reproducer from my real project, i forgot about the shadowRoot. Because in the actual project i am not using the shadowDom. So, that part is not the point of my question. So, Chellappan in his answer is right about that. But the main part of the question is about updated and updateCompleted. Why do I need both to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an element within the Shadow DOM, use `this.shadowRoot`, which refers to the root node of the Shadow DOM of the current web component.

It's important to wait for the component's update cycle to complete before attempting to access its elements. This can be accomplished using the `updateComplete` promise.

```
updated() {
    this.updateComplete.then(()=>{
         console.log("Trying to access div: ",this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#elem'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: It works, but can you elabote why i have to combine update with updateComplete?

"updated: Called whenever the component’s update finishes and the element's DOM has been updated and rendered."
So, my mental model says that the framework will execute the "updated" when all is rerendered and at the end of it complete the updateComplete callback. so, why do i need to combine both to make it work?

Comment: updated gives you a hook to react to changes, updateComplete ensures that all asynchronous tasks, including those in child components or initiated by reactive controllers, have been processed. check this for more info:
https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#reactive-update-cycle

Comment: Maybe i have to look more in detail how the directive is implemented to understand it. What you specifcally say about child components does not fit about the description in the documentation:

"When an element updates, it may cause its children to update as well. By default, the updateComplete promise resolves when the element's update has completed, but does not wait for any children to have completed their updates. ..."

I am not sure if the until directive also counts as a kind of child component.... but then, updateCompleted should not wait for them to be completed.

Comment: The updated callback is called after the update has been requested and the properties have changed,
 but it might be before the component's template is rendered into shadowRoot
 This is particularly true if there are asynchronous tasks involved in the rendering process. If you remove await from fetchData you will be able to access DOM without updateComplete